# detect call or share connection

Tags: ios, objective-c, connection, call

I have a strange issue with my banner .

I implementated like this :

```
bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 430, 320, 50)];}
bannerView.backgroundColor=[UIColor orangeColor];
bannerView.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-6085823141018149/3131322511";
bannerView.rootViewController = self;
[bannerView sizeToFit];
GADRequest *request3 = [GADRequest request];

request3.testDevices = @[ GAD_SIMULATOR_ID, @"MY_TEST_DEVICE_ID" ];
[bannerView loadRequest:request3];
```

and it's work untill i get a call or a  i start a share connection . When this is happen my banner appears like :

[image]

So i found that is happening because it's just it put down all elements with 40 px around . Can  detect when a call is received or a connection is starting ?

Answer (score 0):

To detect a call,

```
 CTCallCenter *ctCallCenter = [[CTCallCenter alloc] init];
    if (ctCallCenter.currentCalls != nil) 
    {
        NSArray* currentCalls = [ctCallCenter.currentCalls allObjects];
        for (CTCall *call in currentCalls)
        {   
            if(call.callState == CTCallStateConnected)
            {
                // Call is in place
            }
        }
    }
```

Bluetooth state can be detected using Core Bluetooth,

See [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBPeripheral_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CBPeripheral/state).